# cronjob command line to update PHPmyAdmin database with SQL query

Tags: php, sql, cron, phpmyadmin

In Bluehost under the cronjob task list I have set up a job that executes every minute.

```
mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword use mydb 
       -e "UPDATE `users` SET val = '1' WHERE name = 'matt'"
```

I believe I am not selecting the database properly as I am using the same username and pass to log into PHPmyAdmin and the SQL query works fine once I have logged into PHPmyAdmin.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: there is no "PHPmyAdmin database". PHPmyAdmin is a script for managing mysql databases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the command line should be

```
mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword -D mydb -e "UPDATE `users` SET val = '1' WHERE name = 'matt'"
```

the `-D databasename` parameter is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You may follow these steps:

```
$ mysql -u <username> -p <enter>
$ <password>
$> use mydb;
$> update user set val = 1 where name = matt;
```

from the command line